# Unable to SSH into freshly installed debian VM, "Permission denied, please try again." error

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine, openssh

I just set up a Debian 7 VM. I can ping my VM from host OS, which is Ubuntu 14.1, but can not ssh into VM. Here is the output of `ssh -v`

EDIT: I am using virtulbox. I am not using any command line utility.

```
chetan@ubuntubox:~$ ssh -v kumar@192.168.56.1
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/chetan/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.56.1 [192.168.56.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/chetan/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/chetan/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/chetan/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/chetan/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/chetan/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/chetan/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/chetan/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/chetan/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA de:47:c2:98:c2:5c:6a:b2:5b:10:dd:99:d0:bb:40:2e
debug1: Host '192.168.56.1' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/chetan/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: kumar@mail.com
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: kumar.chetan@mail.com
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/chetan/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/chetan/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/chetan/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/chetan/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
kumar@192.168.56.1's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

My `/etc/sshd_config` file is untouched and I have tried enabling PasswordAuthentication to yes and nothing helped.

Comment: @garethTheRed, didn't understand when you say "can log in to the VM at the console". My VM boots up fine, I can ping it and use it.

Comment: I am using virtualbox.

Comment: Why did I assume you were using QEMU? Sorry! Anyway, can we assume that you can log in to the guest from the VirtualBox interface using username `kumar`? If so, check that the localization is/was set correctly. If you added the user `kumar` to your guest while it was set to (eg English UK) and your Ubuntu host is set to (eg English US) then any special character you enter in your password will be incorrect when you `ssh` from the host.

Comment: Checked. Both are same. In fact the password is not at all secure it is something like `dontaskme`.

Comment: You could try creating a test user and trying that.  Also, are there any helpful messages in `/var/log/secure`? You can also run `ssh -vvv` for even more debugging info.

Comment: Don't see any `/var/log/secure`! I can login to my host OS from guest OS, i.e. from my Debian VM to my Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Here http://jsbin.com/digiciqociho/1/, sorry the IT guys have blocked pastebin.com, fml :-(

Comment: You should have `sshd` complaining of `Failed password for kumar from...` in that log - you don't, which suggests you're not accessing the VM. Also, you are connecting to `192.168.56.1`. Isn't that the default gateway on VirtualBox (i've not used it for a while)? If so, you're trying to `ssh` to your physical host computer, which probably has a different password.

Comment: It turns out that I had to enable 2nd ethernet card on my guest OS. Done now. :-)